# How to pass data to a fragment from activity when I fill a searchview?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a searchview in activity and there is a fragment in it. When I try to transfer data to a fragment when searching, they do not reach it. How can I do that?
In this method

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: as part of standard android programming, you pass data to a fragment through the intent, and you get data back from the fragment through an interface.  There are already questions on here that have answers explaining how to do that.
If you need to pass data to an existing fragment instead of reloading it, you can access it with an interface as well.

Comment: See the documentation that explains how to communicate with fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#Deliver

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your fragment:

```
    companion object {
    fun newInstance(data: String) = YourFragment().apply {
        this.data= data
    }

}
```

And call the fragment like shown below:

```
  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainFragment,YourFragment.newInstance(yourData)).commit()
```